# how to access the coffee file present inside the views folder of rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have recently joined in job and got project on rails. I am very new to rails, js and ajax . I have a file name update.js.coffee inside view/developer folder. I have developer_controller inside which update action has been defined which updates using ajax the value of particular form element depending on changes of other element.

I am  using the coffee file which does the following work

My `update.js.coffee` file  and its location `\app\views\developer`:

```
 $("#typhos_platform_dev").empty().append("<%=escape_javascript(
 render(:to_partial_path => @platforms, :partial => "platforms" )) %>")
```

As i see we are accessing the `@platforms` in the partial "platforms". Note that, `@platforms` has been defined inside action update and the partial platforms  has been rendered inside index.html.erb. The partial function is takes the value of @platforms and print it in dropdown list.

While running the rails server i noticed coffee file is not even being executed because of which partial is throwing error as it is not able to identify the `@platforms` instance variable.

How to access the coffee variable ??

(As all i didn't found question regarding the coffee file created inside views. All question i found are related to asset pipeline. )

Comment: your `update.js.coffee` looks like `update.js.erb` just rename it!

Answer (score 0):

when you make an ajax call in rails the call should go to your controller execute the action you're calling then send the response to a javascript.erb file located in views/controller/

so if you were to make an ajax call to the action update_dropdown in the developer_controller then you would need a js file in the

> views/developer/

directory named update_dropdown.js.erb. Then you should have access to all of the instance variables

i found  [this article](https://launchschool.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails)  helpful

Comment: Actually, there ae two tabs you can call it as one for QA and other for developers so fro QA same concept has been applied which i mentioned above and that was working fine but here it s not able to ... Still i will try to implemetn as yu said using .js.erb file